# What is the solution to the following recurrence relation with square root: T(n)=T([√n])+logn?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I know that there was a question similar to this but that is with +1. I want to know how will we proceed if we have a logarithmic function there?

I feel that you would try to proceed to the base case, T(n^1/2^k)+log(n^((2^k - 1)/(2^k-2^k-1)).

But what do you do after this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: You might want to check to see if this would be on topic at https://math.stackexchange.com/ which is a maths stack exchange site and thus more relevant for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to expand the recurrence:

```
T(n) = T(n^0.5) + log(n) =
     = T(n^0.25) + log(n^0.5) + log(n) =
     = T(n^0.25) + 0.5 log(n) + log(n) =
     = ...
```

So an alternative form to write this recurrence would be

```
(1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + ...) * log(n) = 2 log(n)
```